# Connecting to a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I'm trying to connect to a database but nothing I try works.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Gerard Foley\Desktop\Northwind.sdf");

conn.Open();
```

No matter what I try I just get the error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I stole the connection string from Database Explorer -> Properties -> Connection String. What am I missing? I can get the tables to show up in a DataGridView fine (by dragging from Data Sources), but I want to use my own UI and queries. I just can't seem to figure this ADO thing out.
Using c# express 2010 and sql server express 2008.

Comment: You connection string is pointing to the database file (for SQL server compact edition).  You need to have an instance of SQL Server Compact Edition running on the machine,  and set your connection string to point to that server instance and the database as it appears within that server instance.

Comment: please do not steal connection strings, its not nice

Comment: GOT IT. I should have been using Sql**Ce**Connection. The connection string was fine.

Answer (score 2):

for the proper connection string to use to connect to SQL Server have a look at:

http://connectionstrings.com

the connection string you are using now is strange, it should contain server name and database name, see link above for examples...

Answer (score 1):

GOT IT. I should have been using Sql**Ce**Connection. The connection string was fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify 'AttachDbFileName' in the connection string. See the examples for sql server express here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008.